# Why the CollectionViewCell is malfunctioning when scrolling up and down?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

### The problem

When scrolling up and down in my (programmatically) created collectionView the cells doesn't seem to dequeued properly. This is resulting in duplication of it contents.

### Video

[Bug replication](https://youtu.be/8hgJGdFdSgQ)

### Wished behaviour

I wish that the cells correctly getting dequeued and that the content does not get duplicated.

### Code snippet

Code snippets are provided via Pastebin below. I had to add some code to satisfy the markdown editor here on SO...

```
open class CollectionDataSource<Provider: CollectionDataProviderProtocol, Cell: UICollectionViewCell>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout where Cell: ConfigurableCell, Provider.T == Cell.T {
```

https://pastebin.com/CzHYxTDD

```
class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell, ConfigurableCell {
}
```

https://pastebin.com/9Nkr3s4B

> If anything else is need, please ask in the comments.

Comment: @SteveO'Connor Take the snippet, review it. The problem is most probably in the dequeing of cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call

```
func configure(_ item: ProductViewModel, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    setupProductImage(with: item.productImage)
    setupStackView()
    setupProductLines(with: item.productLines)
}
```

You create new instance `productLineLabel = UILabel()` inside `setupProductLines()` and add it to the `stackView`

You should change this behavior or rather clear the stack view in `prepareForReuse` method.

Keep in mind, that `addArrangedSubview` increases `suview`s retain count for newly added elements. If you stop your applications execution using **Debug View Hierarchy** button (fig 1), most likely you will see more labels than you expect in the cell.

[image: fig 1] fig 1.

Comment: What would be the logic that goes inside the prepareForReuse? I tried to remove the stackview from the super view or remove specific subviews. But it didn't had any effect.

Comment: @KevinVugts, `prepareForReuse` basically does what it says. It prepares cell for being reused. Which usually understood as resetting cell to its initial state. In your case it should remove subviews from the stackview, clear images from imageViews and so on. I had a fresh look on your code today and i have more to say: 1. StackView as well as any other subviews can be set up only once `awakeFromNib` is good place for that. No need to do it every time 2. If you don't have any specific reason of using multiple UILabels for text rows, why not use one multiline label?

Comment: can you update your answer with the code that is the solution?

Comment: I can, if you give me minimal working project so i can test how it works.

Comment: I fixed it myself! Nevertheless, thanks for your help. Please review my answer below and confirm that this is what you meant!

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Each time I call:

```
func configure(_ item: ProductViewModel, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    setupProductImage(with: item.productImage)
    setupStackView()
    setupProductLines(with: item.productLines)
}
```

I create a new instance of productLineLabel = UILabel()
Therefore it will be duplicated each time the configure(_ item:) is being called from the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

### The solution

I used prepareForReuse recommended by llb to remove the subviews that were kind of class UIStackview (containing UILabels). I wrote the following extension to make this less tedious:

```
func addSubviews(with subviews: [UIView], in parent: UIView) {
    subviews.forEach { parent.addSubview($0) }
  }
```

### The implementation

The only thing what was left to do was calling the custom extension function from prepareForReuse like so:

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    let foundStackView = subviews.filter({$0.isKind(of: UIStackView.self)})[0] as? UIStackView
    guard let labels = foundStackView?.arrangedSubviews.filter({$0.isKind(of: UILabel.self)}) else { return }
    foundStackView?.removeArrangedSubviews(labels, shouldRemoveFromSuperview: true)
  }
```

Credits go to llb, see comments below! <3 Thanks.

Comment: it is what i meant, however you don't need to scan subviews every time, as you always have reference to the `stackView`. In your case `foundStackView` equals `stackView`, so you can skip that step.

Comment: Try https://pastebin.com/3SfLuQcX. Haven't tested, but it should work. Good luck!